# Why won't Visual Studio debugger properly evaluate expressions that involve generic type arguments?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

In the following code:

```
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            var listy = new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Now };
            MyMethod(listy);
        }

        static void MyMethod<T>(List<T> myList)
        {
            // put breakpoint here
        }
```

If I break in the debugger, open QuickWatch on "myList", I see:

```
myList
   [0]
   Raw View
```

If I select the "[0]" node and click Add Watch, the expression that is added to Watch:

`(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<System.DateTime>(myList)).Items[0]`

This expression seems correct, and yet, the watch window shows the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection)'
>   has some invalid arguments

This seems like a bug in the debugger. Why does this happen? And is it documented anywhere?

Comment: It has trouble with myList somehow, it works if you use a static variable.  Post to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Microsoft [marked the bug report I filed as Fixed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/684678/visual-studio-debugger-c-expression-evaluator-doesnt-work-with-bound-generic-types), so hopefully this won't happen in dev11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the C#'s expression evaluator's overload resolution logic. The combination of invoking a generic type constructor and passing a bound generic seems to be a key.  Removing either of these seems to fix the problem.  For example you can invoke the expression mentioned by explicitly casting `myList` to `ICollection<DateTime>` (this doesn't fix all cases I tried though)

Here's a sample program I wrote to narrow down the problem

```
class C<T> {
    public C(ICollection<T> collection) {

    }
}

static void Example<T>(ICollection<T> collection) {
}
```

At the same break you can try the following evaluations

- `Example(myList)` - Works without error
- `new C<DateTime>(myList)` - Fails with the same error

At this point i think you should file a bug on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio). It's definitely a bug (similar code works fine in VB.Net)

Comment: Thank you! I opened a connect ticket @ https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/684678/visual-studio-debugger-c-expression-evaluator-doesnt-work-with-bound-generic-types . I guess I'll go with always using the workaround and hope for the best.

Answer (score 0):

Looks that way. I've been able to replicate the error. `Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<T>` has only one constructor accepting `ICollection<T>` and `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`. Also, explicitly casting to `ICollection<T>` works:

```
(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<System.DateTime>((ICollection<DateTime>)myList)).Items[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found this workaround. But I'm more concerned about why this happen, so that I can understand whether or not this workaround is always applicable (I'm authoring a Visual Studio extension that has to do with debugging, so it's important to me to understand the root cause)